# Laravel - How to change localhost base URL

Tags: php, laravel, .htaccess, xampp, localhost

I have a Laravel 7 project and I'm using XAMPP for my localhost. The project folder is in C:\xampp\htdocs\eegore-new. I've copied my .htaccess file from the public folder (the other one still exist in public directory), and put it in to the root directory and changed the server.php into index.php so I can now access my my application via localhost with this url -> http:://localhost/eegore-new. But once I clicked my login button on that page, it redirected me to http:://localhost/login which shows 'Object Not Found, Error 404' while it should redirected me to http:://localhost/eegore-new/login so the page can load correctly.

I've changed my APP_URL in .env file to <'http:://localhost/eegore-new-copy'> and tried to change my .htaccess file in my root folder.

This is my folder structure :

[My folder structure screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v3wRk.png)

This is the .htaccess in my root folder, I tried RewriteBase but its not working:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews -Indexes
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /eegore-new/

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
    RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

And this is the .htacess in my public folder:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews -Indexes
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
    RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

I have to make all the routes functioning just like http::/localhost/eegore-new/login or /user or /other but I'm not really sure what to do or where to start actually and I know nothing about .htaccess.

Any help will be really appreciated, thanks in advance!

Comment: Instead of moving the htaccess to the root to be able to access your website without adding /public
just create a Virtual Host in XAMPP, it will make it easier for you without missing around with the default folder structure of laravel.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I've tried to make a Virtual Host in XAMPP and it works perfectly!

For others that might be facing with the same problems, here is several links that you can use to make your own Virtual Host in XAMPP :
1. https://medium.com/@ajtech.mubasheer/configure-a-virtual-host-for-laravel-project-in-xampp-for-windows-10-d3f0068e7e1b
2. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=r5hr2nAa7-M&t=195s
3. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SrK7yVwkE-k